# What's the simplest (smallest) way to dim a DC LED strip with a switch?

Tags: current, led-strip

I apologize for asking about what is probably the most simple problem to you folks but it seems I am ignorant of all the basics of electronics and Google did not help me here.

This is a 12v DC system.

When I say 'switch' I mean I want 'high beams' and 'low beams' effectively.   High being the full amount of current that the strip wants and low being 1/2 or 1/4 of what it wants. I've attached pics of the specs for one strip that claims to be dimmable.  I do not need exact specified amounts of current. My purpose is simply reduced light output and reduced energy consumption at the flip of a switch.  But I do want it to be efficient in that it doesnt just 'burn off' the excess current as heat.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Thank you.
[image]
[image]

Comment: If you are *ignorant of all the basics of electronics and Google did not help me* then any simple proposal made here will almost certainly appear complex to you.

Comment: How are you planning to power these strips in the first place? How many strips are you planning to use? Please provide a wiring diagram.

Comment: Get two LED strips with half the brightness and use both for high beam and one of them for low beam?

Comment: Don't ever post a screenshot. If you're posting a screenshot, there's a better way to do it. Do that instead.

Comment: Sorry about the screenshots. I have been incredibly short of time lately.  Thanks everyone for your comments and answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most efficient way is to use a circuit that pulses the 12V at high enough frequency to not be seen as flickering, then determine experimentally to find the duty cycle that yields perceived 50% dimness.

Basically a 555 set up as an oscillator an a N-channel mosfet between the cathodes and GND would do it.
Or an Arduino Promini and AOD508 (or equivalent Low Rds part) if you want to control the duty cycle in software instead of using Rs & Cs.

Since these appear to be "dumb" (vs individually controllable chip) light strips, 4 transistors are needed, one for each color. Some mixing of colors may be needed to achieve the color and dimness you wish.  In which case, a Promini + 4 transistor approach would be smarter.  If you look the at controller at this site, something similar would be found.
https://www.superbrightleds.com/moreinfo/clearance-led-strip-and-tape-lights/outdoor-rgbw-led-strip-lights-weatherproof-12v-led-tape-light-w-white-and-multicolor-leds-245-lumensft/1711/#tab/specifications

Comment: I did this a couple years ago with the 555 and it was beautiful. Thanks for helping me jumpstart my first "hello world" electronics project. I've since become an occasional arduino tinkerer when my kids need a new toy.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using LED strips, you should be using the COTS equipment made for that purpose.  Specifically "dimmers" and "amplifiers".   All of these use PWM.

I would couple a dimmer to an amplifier.  Have your switch either use the dimmer, or bypass the dimmer.

The dimmer takes in 12V power + and -.  It then has a rheostat, which decides how bright.  It then pulses the power, in PWM manner, i.e. on and off rapidly. AT 25% power, the pulse is on for 1 tick then off for 3 ticks.  Ticks are too fast to see, so it doesn't visibly flicker.

Pulsing is done on the DC - rail. The DC + rail is passed straight through. That's because LED strips are as *positive ground*.

Have the dimmer output feed an **amplifier**.  The amplifier takes in 12 VDC power + and -, and also takes in a PWM signal at 12V peak (from the dimmer).   The output is 12V + and - power, with the - leg pulsed with the PWM signal.  Drive the LEDs from this.

Use an SPDT switch (called a "3-way" if you're using common mains apparatus).  The common goes to the amplifier input.  Input 1 goes to the dimmer output.  Input 2 goes to 12V MINUS rail.  This means the amplifier will receive either continious-on (100% PWM), or a PWM set to your preference (say 25% PWM).

For small setups, there's a way to omit the amplifier and come off the dimmer directly - however I don't recommend it because it'll involve the switch switching full current, and that will cause arcing damage to the switch.

Comment: Thank you. I will be studying each element of your answer and will try to wrap my brain around it before giving it a try.